# IOS/objective-c/xcode: Instantiate DetailView Controller in Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, presentviewcontroller

I had some code for launching a modal view controller created in storyboard with a storyboard ID.  For a new situation, I am trying to adapt it to present a ViewController that is actually the detail view of a table in the main navigational system.  I'm trying to jump around in the app if that is possible.

In this case, the VC should not be modal.  Instead, I  want to take the user to the normal detail view of a table.

To make it more challenging, I need the detail view to have the object data.  Fortunately, this should be present in the starting VC.

Here is my code for launching  a modal VC.

```
 UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
         detailVC *newVC =
         [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];
         //pass object to new VC
         detailVC.object = _object;//pass data object
         UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: dareVC];
         [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

**Edit:**  Following code does launch non-modal VC.  However, initial detail view is devoid of data.  The data is saved so if I come back to it, the data is there but initially, I get generic screen with no data.

```
  detailVC *secondViewController =
         [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
         secondViewController.object=_object;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  detailVC *secondViewController =
         [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
         secondViewController.object=_object;
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

First instantiate it. 
Then set the data. 
Then push it.